# Display suggestedActions options in vertical

Tags: azure, chatbot

I added suggestedActions to chatbot. But it displays all options in Horizontal and it is not showing full texts.

Below the code

```
var msg = new builder.Message(session)
.text("What would you like assistance with?")
.suggestedActions(
    builder.SuggestedActions.create(
        session, [
                builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "Texas Workforce Commission", "1. Texas Workforce Commission"),
                builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "Jobs Y’all", "2. Jobs Y’all")
            ]
        ));
    session.send(msg);
```

Attached the screenshot.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zl5Jn.png)

Questions:

1. Right now the options are displaying horizontally. I need to display the options vertically. How do i do that?
2. And the first option in the list is truncated automatically. How should i display all options so they are not truncated?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do this in your code. This is a problem of how the cards you send are rendered by each [channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-channels?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) and i think for most of the channels there isn't a way neither.

But if you use [WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) then the answer could by **yes**. It depends on your React/JavaScript skills. WebChat is a React app which is compiled to javascript and bundled to one botchat.js. In this case you have two options:

1. Modify the React code which will produce a modified botchat.js
2. Modify the final botchat.js

I myself ended up modifying the react code and this is the only option i can recommend to you. It may take you some time but in the end it's worth it.